# How to set is modfied manually for a virtual property in EF, I already know how to set the normal properties and collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to set is modfied manually for a virtual property in Entity Framework.

Currently, I know how to set for normal properties, however when I was
Navigating the properties inside the PropertyInfo class, I can only find GetMethod.IsVirtual
When I set the property to modifed.

```
 public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }



    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }



    public int? GradeId { get; set; }



    public virtual Grade Grade { get; set; }



    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

I want to update only fields marked as modified, In this example I am trying to mark ICollection as modified using entity-framework,

```
ctx.Entry(student).Property(x => x.Courses).IsModified = true;
```

I am getting this exception

System.ArgumentException: 'The property 'Courses' on type 'Student' is not a primitive or complex property. The Property method can only be used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method.'

Answer (score 0):

Because `IsModifed` does not work with the collection, it works with single properties

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what is the solution in this case? what's the best practices to handle this case, Mr. Vivek.